# getting post title and applying it to a url to fetch information from xml

Tags: wordpress, post, title

Here's the code I am using and I'll try my best to explain what  I need ( I am using wordpress)

```
function Count(){
$feed_url = "http://website.com/summary.xml?subfolder=POST TITLE";
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"$feed_url"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
$xmlFile = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlFile); 
return $xml->count;
}
```

Basically My site checks this site for activity. IF it finds activity it says ACTIVE if not it says Not Active. Each post looks for different activity corresponding to the post title for example:

"Site A" has Foobar 1, Foobar 2, Foobar 3. My site also has the same names as the post title to look for activity. I can't figure out how to get the post title to dynamically change according to the post it corresponds to.

I can't use php within php so  php echo the_title();  is out of the question but I need EXACTLY what this does except I don't want to echo it, i just need it to be placed in the back of a URL so the site knows what info to grab for which post.

I hop that makes sense,
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I did, Can't you just add the post title to your feed url with [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) like this (I am assuming you are inside the loop):

```
$feed_url = "http://website.com/summary.xml?subfolder=".get_the_title();
```

Or pass it as an argument to your function:

```
function Count($post_title){
    $feed_url = "http://website.com/summary.xml?subfolder=".$post_title;
    // ...
```

And call it inside the loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $activity = Count(get_the_title()); ?>
```